# How to update cell value to max if value is smaller than other cell in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like cell A to have the max value that another cell B has ever had. How can I do that? Cell B changes value dynamically according to a `=GoogleFinance()` formula (every few seconds or so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to accomplish that, is through a script, Google Apps Script that is.

### Script

```
function getMax() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cValue = sh.getRange("C2").getValue();
  var hRange = sh.getRange("B3"), hValue = hRange.getValue();
  if(cValue > hValue) {
    hRange.setValue(cValue);
  }
}
```

### Trigger

[image]

### Explained

The script is retrieving the two values, at 1 minute intervals, and compares them. If the "real" value if higher than the highest value, then the highest will be replaced by the "real' value.

### How-to

Add the script under `Tools>Script editor`. Press the bug button to authenticate the script (as it need access to the Google Spreadsheet). Select `Resources\Current project's triggers` in the script editor and set it to the screenshot given.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[get max value from formula](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdFlwOXZ4bHFoWjFYRVd5SFlHSHJfQWc&usp=sharing)**

### Second Best

```
=MAX(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG", "HIGH", "01-01-2011", TEXT(NOW(), "dd-MM-yyyy"), "1"),"", 2))
```

### Explained

This formula will show all the highest day values of the Google share, from the beginning of 2011. The `INDEX` formula will show only the second column and the `MAX` formula will show only the highest value.

Comment: I got it working with the Google Apps Script method that you describe above. I hooked it to the specific spreadsheet that I needed, and after waiting for a bit, I saw it updating the value.